# (Mac OS X) Will Internet Recovery erase anything in my Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, osx-yosemite

I accidentally did the Internet Recovery by pressing Command+Option+R. Will this erase anything? (Files, Partitions, etc.) Also, will it affect my Mac in anyway? Thank you.

Comment: I don't understand.  If you performed the operation already, it is a little late, to ask what it does.

Comment: You have your answer from reverie if you didn't use disk utility to erase the partition before recovery

Answer (score 1):

It leaves your personal files, installed apps and settings (desktop, app, etc. settings) untouched. It seems to only replace system files, and may resolve system file related problems.

Did it successfully on OS X Yosemite 10.10.5 system to eliminate the problem described in this post:

http://forums.appleinsider.com/t/156536/macs-hard-drive-fills-up-before-my-eyes-gbs-disappear-in-minutes